# Fixing marker color and axis scaling with d3 hexbin

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I think there's a lot to this post, and I'll probably offer a bounty if I can't get this solved in earlier than 2 days because it's a graph I really want to make! I am trying to make something along the lines of the hexbin graph that shows up [in this Washington Post article on baseball players](https://www.washingtonpost.com/graphics/sports/mlb-launch-angles-story/?utm_term=.b75df61a99e0). (have to scroll down a bit)

I am building off of the [really good hexbin starter code here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4248145). I am fairly new with JS and d3 and I am struggling a bit with a few adjustments, including:

- rescaling (the axes, the data, I'm not sure) so the hexbins take up most of the  container, even if the Y values are very small (on a 0 to 1 scale, for example).
- currently the color scale is based simply on the number of data points that fall into each hexagon locations. However I'd like to update the hexagon colors to be a function (the average) of some additional column of data that goes with the points.

Here is the code from the link I shared above:

```js
// A. Create the SVG container starter code
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


// B. Random data
  // change which randomX and randomY are used. 
  // my baseball graph wll have Y values in the range -1 to 1
  // create a 3rd value in the points vector, for using to compute color
var randomX = d3.randomNormal(60, 20),
    randomY = d3.randomNormal(height / 2, 80),
    // randomY = d3.randomNormal(0, 0.3),
    // randomX = d3.randomNormal(width / 2, 80),
    colorZ = d3.randomNormal(0.35, 0.1),
    points = d3.range(2000).map(function() { return [randomX(), randomY(), colorZ()]; });

// C. The scales
// color scale starter code
var color = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateLab("white", "steelblue"))
    .domain([0, 20]);

// hexbin starter code
var hexbin = d3.hexbin()
  .radius(8)
  .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]]);

// X and Y scale starter code (my changes commented out - didnt work) 
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, width])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 60])
    .range([height, 0]);


// D. append everything to grpah starte code
g.append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "hexagon")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(hexbin(points))
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", hexbin.hexagon())
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.length); });

g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickSizeOuter(-width));

g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSizeOuter(-height));
```

```css
.hexagon {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="700" height="500"></svg>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-hexbin.v0.2.min.js"></script>
```

On each of my two questions from above:

**Axis adjustments** - Not being able to get this is struggling. My actual Y data will be in the range (-1 to 1), and test data in the code above with data in this range can be added by changing the comments. I've tried changing the domain and range in the axis scales but that didn't help.

**Color based on 3rd parameter rather than count** - I think this will be difficult, and I'm not sure if its possible, but I'd like to know. If the points data looked like this:

```
points = [
  {"x": 2.5, "y": 4, "count": 1}
  {"x": 3.5, "y": 3, "count": 1}
  {"x": 2.7, "y": 2, "count": 1}
  {"x": 2.8, "y": 3, "count": 1}
  {"x": 3.5, "y": 4, "count": 1}
  {"x": 2.5, "y": 3, "count": 1}
  {"x": 4.5, "y": 4, "count": 1}
  {"x": 1.8, "y": 2, "count": 1}
  ...
]
```

then essentially the hex colors are coming from a sum of the count column. Rather, i would like to use my own third column, and base the color on the average of that column within the coordinate values that get grouped to each hex.

```
points = [
  {"x": 2.5, "y": 4, "value": 2}
  {"x": 3.5, "y": 3, "value": 3.5}
  {"x": 2.7, "y": 2, "value": 3}
  {"x": 2.8, "y": 3, "value": 9}
  {"x": 3.5, "y": 4, "value": 8}
  {"x": 2.5, "y": 3, "value": 6}
  {"x": 4.5, "y": 4, "value": 5.3}
  {"x": 1.8, "y": 2, "value": 7}
  ...
]
```

and the color would then be based on the average of the "value" column for each bin.

Any help with this is appreciated, I know this is a long post, but I've struggled a bit with this today and being able to make these visualizations would help me a ton!

Comment: Regarding the color issue: if you don't want to use the count, this is not technically speaking a hexa**BIN** anymore! It's something else... a (histogram) bin just counts the number of occurrences.

Comment: Also, i'd suggest splitting this question in two (after all, asking questions is free!)... that way, it will be easier to get good, proper answers. The way it is right now it's simply too much work for the answerer.

Comment: thanks @GerardoFurtado - the questions are somewhat related so I originally made 1 post but I can split into 2. Are you saying that the color issue is likely not solvable with d3.hexbin() then?

Comment: No no, it's certainly solvable! I'm just saying that you won't have a *hexabin* anymore. So, people that know data visualization will find it funny, like *"this guy wants a histogram which is not a histogram..."*. regarding splitting the question, you can always link each other, so users can click and see what's going on on the other question.

Comment: Yeah I guess it's technically not a hexbin anymore. I'd actually like the "bin" part of hexbin to go towards the size, so that the count factor impacts each hexagons size, but I am also not sure if that's possible and want to get these earlier issues resolved.

Comment: They are both possible. Just make this question easier (by breaking in two) for anyone trying to answer it.